# Are there any non-jQueryUI Sliders out there?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm avoiding using jQuery UI but need a nice slider. Any help?

**EDIT**
I don't like jQueryUI because the slider is the only component I need so I'd like to go light weight with it.

Comment: Why are you avoiding jQuery UI? Can you not just use the one component?

Comment: you're avoiding using jquery, yet you've tagged your question with jquery? why? and why not jquery?

Comment: Your question is vague.  Are you not wanting any jQuery plugins at all or just don't want jQuery plugins that require jQueryUI?

Comment: Also, what kind of slider?  A Content Slider like an image carousel?  Can you post an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another one:

https://github.com/borisdiakur/jquery.slideControl.js

Live demo:

http://borisdiakur.com/jquery.slideControl.js/demo.html

Answer (score 2):

- http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/slider/
- http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Slider
- http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/slider/slider-ticks.html

And native js: http://www.blueshoes.org/en/javascript/slider/

Comment: Until the OP clarifies his question, I'm thinking he's looking for a jQuery plugin that does not require jQuery UI.

Answer (score 2):

You say that you want to avoid jQuery UI because you don't want the weight of all the components.  I fully agree, and so does the jQuery UI team.  This is why you can [choose which components to compile](http://jqueryui.com/download).  By my reckoning, the CSS and JS for the slider on its own comes to about 80kb -- which really isn't very much.

Comment: Compared to 5kb 80kb is muuuuuuch.